# Google Home Smart Home integration

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

Alexa has two kind of Skills: Custom and Smart Home. Smart Home Skills support a predefined API to interact with smart home devices (lights, etc). I can't find anything close to this in the documentation for Google Smart Home. Should I have to develop all the dialogs from scratch or Google have something already done?

Answer (score 1):

Google now has a special kind of action called Smart Home App.
It's similar to Alexa's smart home skill.

You can find its document here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/

To create a smart home app, follow the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app

Hope this will help you out. Good Luck.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)